# Pass touch events through zone in a moving UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, uiviewanimation

I need to make some sort of tutorial in my app. The idea is that the user sees kind of a transparent but slightly darkened overlay with a hole in it. This hole is the only zone that lets touches through. The solution to this problem is simple — you just have to implement `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` or even `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` where you check the zone and pass through only the touches you want to pass through.

Then, for instance, this view starts to move. The movement is caused by some basic animation like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
  self.tutorialHoleView.center = CGPointMake(self.tutorialHoleView.center.x-160.0, self.tutorialHoleView.center.y);
} completion:nil];
```

You would expect a view to keep passing touches only in a specified zone but that's not true — here we are talking about the `self.layer.presentationLayer` property of the view. So, you need to create a superview where you do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  for (UIView * subview in [self subviews]) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[ETTutorialFlashlightView class]]) {
      ETTutorialHoleView * tutorialView = (ETTutorialHoleView *)subview;
      CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
      CGRect presentationFrame = [tutorialView.layer.presentationLayer frame];
      if ((point.x >= presentationFrame.origin.x+presentationFrame.size.width/2.0-75.0) && (point.x <= presentationFrame.origin.x+presentationFrame.size.width/2.0+75.0) && (point.y >= presentationFrame.origin.y+presentationFrame.size.height/2.0-75.0) && (point.y <= presentationFrame.origin.y+presentationFrame.size.height/2.0+75.0)) {
        [self.tutorialView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I've made this to pass touches to my superview:

```
self.tutorialHoleView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Surprisingly, this doesn't work at all. It doesn't pass tap events, not to speak about swipe events which I need to be passed too. So, my question is — how do I pass touch events through a specific zone in a moving UIView? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

add this in options of animation block, UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction.

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = 1 <<  1, // turn on user interaction while animating
```

This will invoke your touchesBegan method, but at the end frame only not the touches that are in the frame while moving.